# How to use React.createContext() with react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-context

I am trying to use React.createContext() with react router but at the moment has been impossible.

```
const Context = React.createContext()

<Context.Provider value={{ valueTest: 1 }}>
  <HashRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route
        exact
        path="/"
        render={() => <h1>HelloWorld</h1>} />
    </Switch>
  </HashRouter>
</Context.Provider>
```

I always get this error

Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like an issue rendering your context value, the following code works well

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { HashRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Hello from "./Hello";
import { Context } from "./context";
const App = () => (
  <Context.Provider value={{ valueTest: 1 }}>
    <HashRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/"
          render={props => <Hello {...props} name="CodeSandbox" />}
        />
      </Switch>
    </HashRouter>
  </Context.Provider>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

context.js

```
import React from "react";
export const Context = React.createContext();
```

Hello.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Context } from "./context";

export default ({ name }) => (
  <Context.Consumer>
    {value => (
      <h1>
        Hello {name} {value.valueTest}!
      </h1>
    )}
  </Context.Consumer>
);
```

**[Working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/o93v15noky)**